# How to calculate the average of one file based on condition in another file?

Tags: r

I have two binary files with the same dimensions: the first represents correlation between 2 data and the second represents landuse map.I want to take the average of my correlations(first file) based on the landuse values (intervals),the values of this file range from 0 to 7. whenever the values in the second file range between 0-1, calculate the corresponding average in the first file and return the result,do the same thing with 2-3,3-4,5-6,7-8.

Here are the two files:

1- to read the first file correlation map:

```
   conne <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
  corr<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

2- to read the second file land cover map:

```
    conne1<- file("C:\\use.bin","rb")
   cus<- readBin(conne1, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut()` to create the intervals and `aggregate()` to calculate the mean.

```
 (cusBREAK <- cut(cus,0:6))
 (corrMEAN <- aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean))
```

Comment: So this will make Levels: `(0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6]`
`(corrMEAN <- aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean))`
  `Group.1   x
1   (0,1] NaN
2   (1,2] NaN
3   (2,3] NaN
4   (3,4] NaN
5   (4,5] NaN
6   (5,6] NaN`   I wonder I got all NAN and what if I want to change the interval.the intervals here are from 0-1 and 1-2   what if I want 1-1.5 and 1.5 -2 .....

Comment: Add to the question a sample of youy data (type `dput(conne)` and paste the result, I can't download from my computer). To change the intervals, chenge the vector `0:6` (a vector of integer from 0 to 6) to `seq(0, 6, by=.5)`